# Anchor to left margin of the page instead of beginning of line

Tags: hyperref, links

This may be a very minor thing, but when I click on an internal link within the document (produced by `hyperref`), the link takes me to the beginning of the line of text, moving the page horizontally (undesired) as well as vertically (desired), i.e. up/down to the page I need.

Instead, I would like it to take me to the left-most margin of the page at the same point down the page.

This is mainly (but not only) because I zoom into the page and centre it carefully, and when I click a link it always moves it to the wrong place.

I hope these screenshots makes it clearer.

This is what clicking to the "Chapter 3" anchor should do:
[image]
And this is what it shouldn't do:
[image]

Is there a way to do this?

Comment: Does this behaviour depend on the pdf viewer?